# Recurrence relation $a_{n} = a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+n$

Tags: recurrence-relations

How to solve this recurrence relation?

$a_{n} = a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+n,a_{1}=a_{0}=1$

What I have tried:

$r^2 = r + 1  \rightarrow r = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$

non-homogeneous part:

$$
\begin{split}
a_{n} &= cn+b \implies c(n)+b = c(n-1) + b + c(n-2) + b + n\\
0     &= -3c+b+n(c+1) \implies c+1 = 0 \iff c=-1 \implies b = -4 \\
a_{n} &= c_{0} \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n
       + c_{1} \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n -n-4
\end{split}
$$

putting $a_{0}$ and $a_{1}$ in recurrence relation gives $c_{0} = (\frac{1}{2})(5+\frac{7}{\sqrt{5}})$ and $c_{1} = (\frac{1}{2})(5-\frac{7}{\sqrt{5}})$.

I am sure my answer is wrong because for n greater than 1 it doesn't work. help me correct my mistake, please.

Comment: there is no typo. what part doesn't make sense?

Comment: what a dumb mistake should i delete my question?

Comment: no, leave it. it is a good illustration of how to solve these things if someone needs a reference

Comment: Note : In general, to locate particular solutions of a recurrence relation with a non-linear term, you may use various ansatz and see which works. For a recurrence relation like this, if you try the function $a_n = cn+d$ then $cn+d = c(n-1)+d + c(n-2)+d + n = n(2c+1) + (2d-3)$, so we get $c = -1$ and $d=3$. Thus, a particular solution of the recurrence is $b_n = -n+3$. But now, $a_n -b_n = c_n$ satisfies the recurrence $c_n = c_{n-1} + c_{n-2}$, and now you are in good shape because you can find $c_n$ using the usual tricks (or it's the Fibonacci translated, so you know the answer). Finish.

Comment: Alt. hint: write it as $\,\left(a_n+n+3\right) = \left(a_{n-1}+(n-1)+3\right) + \left(a_{n-2}+(n-2)+3\right)\,$, so $\,a_n+n+3\,$ is a Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the last equation
$$
0 = n(c+1) + (b-3c),
$$
which implies $c+1 = 0 \iff c=-1$ and $b = 3c = -3 \ne -4$.

Comment: OMG. thank you. should i delete my question?

Comment: @gigili no, leave it. it is a good illustration of how to solve these things if someone needs a reference

Answer (score 2):

Here's another possible approach using generating functions (a standard approach for many linear recurrences):
Let us define $A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$
Then, we have:
$$a_n x^n=a_{n-1} x^n+a_{n-2} x^n+n x^n$$
Summing:
$$A(x)-x-1=x(A(x)-1)+x^2 A(x)+x\frac {d(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n})}{dx}$$
Thus, we get:
$$A(x)=\frac { \frac {x}{(1-x)^2}+1}{1-x-x^2}$$
The coefficient of $x^n$ in this polynomial gives $a_n$. That can now be found out using partial fractions.